# Include Roles from external database in the Access Token

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am doing login from Azure AD.Client is SPA(angular using MSAL). If user is not Authenticated, it redirect to Microsoft Login Screen (using MSAL). On successful login, it return an access token.
My roles will be stored in a database. I need to  add the roles of that user as part of claim in access token. I am not finding the way to do it.
I do not want to make another call from SPA to API to get the DB roles.
Please suggest some good approach.
Any links explaining the approach will also be very helpful.

I am still in design phase but not able to find the best approach.
In one microsoft site, i found that we can fetch the roles from DB but details were not there.
most of the places, it is written that we need to provide roles in Azure AD users menifest file.

Answer (score 1):

In regular Azure AD, the "roles" claim is exclusively sourced from app role assignments for the signed-in user (or groups the user is a member of), to the app roles for the app the user is signing in to.

There's no feature currently in Azure AD which will connect to an arbitrary database, make a database query in the appropriate form, and include the results in the roles claim in the resulting ID Token.

I can think of three options to achieve your scenario:

1. After sign-in, call an API to retrieve the roles. Though you mention this is not desirable, it's probably the simplest approach, so it's worth listing. As a result of the user's sign-to you app, you app will usually obtain an access token to an API. If you set up your API to be [secured with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-overview) (directly, or [through Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad)), your SPA could simply get the necessary access token as part of sign-in, and at that point it's trivial to make a REST call to retrieve the role details for the user (and possibly other information useful to rendering your app).
2. Synchronize (or copy) your role information from your database to Azure AD. For each role, create an app role in the Azure AD app registration. For each user-role association, either create an app role assignment to directly assign the user (user -> app role), or assign a group to the app role and add the user to the group (user -> group -> app role. Keeping this in sync is probably not trivial, so if your scenario allow to move the role information to Azure AD app role assignment, you can forget the database entirely (making Azure AD the authoritative location). Of course, this might not work for your specific case.
3. Use Azure AD B2C and a custom sign-in policy. You could [create an Azure AD B2C tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-tenant), set up a [custom sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom) to [use your (regular) Azure AD tenant as the identity provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom), and configure the policy to [enhance the claims by calling a REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile) to retrieve your roles. In this approach, you still need to have a REST API which can provide the role information, so rather than doing the setup  and migrating your app, you may prefer simply calling the API from your SPA (option 1, in this list).

Comment: Thanks a lot Philippe for the information. Can we call the Rest API from Azure AD in the same way as you said it is possible with Azure AD B2C.

Comment: That's not currently possible, no.

Comment: We can not make any changes in AAD side, hence the 2nd option i can not opt. 3rd is not possible with AAD. If i use 1st approach, then i need to make another call from SPA to API to get roles. Now at my SPA end, i will have two objects. One is access Token and 2nd is Roles. But Other API will have Role based Authorization.[Authorize(Role="Manager")] and it will expect Roles as part of claim in the access token. How i will make role as part of claim in the token and send it to API. May be some code at SPA we can do it (even though i have not tried it),but just thinking will it be right approach

Comment: If you require the claims in the access token, then you must have the app role assignments represented in Azure AD. Alternatively, you'd need to update your API to do the same lookup/API request to fetch the users role, and take that into consideration by the `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: Thanks Philippe. Your suggestions helped me a lot.